# Why CAShapeLayerLineJoin doesn't compile on tvOS?

Tags: ios, swift, tvos

This doesn't compile:

`let a: CAShapeLayerLineJoin = CAShapeLayerLineJoin.miter`

Error:

`Type 'CAShapeLayerLineJoin' (aka 'NSString') has no member 'miter'`

neither `round` or `bevel`

The same code compiles using iOS target. tvOS has deployment target 9.0. Here is the documentation for `CAShapeLayerLineJoin`: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/quartzcore/cashapelayerlinejoin It says available on tvOS 9.0+
Also, when I cmd-click on it, it leads me to the same definition as the iOS target.

Edit: I linked to the wrong doc. The correct one says `CAShapeLayerLineJoin` available from tvOS 12+.

Any ideas?

Comment: Why the -1 vote?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes but this has nothing to do with deployment target or SDK.   It depends on the Swift language version. You have two different projects or targets, and they are using two different versions of Swift. On the `tvOS` target, the Swift version is older and this is a constant String, `kCALineJoinMiter`.

Comment: Right, I forgot to upgrade the tvOS target to Swift 4.2. The documentation should be clearer about this...